# кодировка mysql

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка, phpmyadmin

[image: кракенозябры]

Есть .sql файл исходную кодировку которого я не знаю. Его импортировал в phpmyadmin. Проблема в отображении символов. Латиницу и цифры показывает нормально. Сравнение стоит utf-8_general_ci и в базе в таблице. Пробовал cp-1251_general_ci и все равно тоже самое. При выводе на сайт символы точно такие же. Пробовал при выводе

```
mysql_query ("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $bd);
mysql_query ("set character_set_client='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");
```

символы все равно такие же.
**если через php выполнить INSERT то новые строки в кириллице отображаются нормально.**

Comment: так откройте .sql файл и узнайте кодировку

Comment: открыл, есть такая запись DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: @ЖалгасАжибаев вам говорят не про строку `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` а про то, какая кодировка самого файла......сам файл должен быть в `UTF-8 без BOM`   для наглядности: http://s019.radikal.ru/i628/1602/e4/01025632aac9.jpg

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в описание вопроса я говорил что исходную кодировку .sql файла я не знаю. Возможно, я не правильно понимаю ваш вопрос. Не могли вы перефразировать детальней.

Comment: @ЖалгасАжибаев а в чем составляет сложность посмотреть кодировку этого самого файла? сложно открыть его в `notepad++` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский понимаете, я не знаю что значит словосочетание "кодировка файла", только примерно догадываюсь. Раз мы выяснили я тупой, а значит открыв файл в notepad++ и не найдя слово "кодировка", естественно начинаю искать что нибудь знакомое, понял что в этой куче mysql параметров везде фигурирует utf-8. Ок, что мне с этим делать? перевод базы в сравнение cp-1251_general_ci ничего не дает.

Comment: @ЖалгасАжибаев вы посмотрели картинку, которую я прикрепил в комментарии? Если еще нет, то очень настоятельно рекомендую. Именно в ней нарисована суть того,  о чем вас спрашивают ) ...... открывайте свой файл `.sql` через `notepad++` в верхней панели находите слово `кодировка`... нажимаете...... там покажут исходную кодировку файла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Откройте sql файл в текстовом редакторе и посмотрите в какой он кодировке. Очень похоже на Win-1252. В таких ситуациях очень помогает такая шпаргалка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: открыл через блокнот есть вот такая запись - DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8, однако по шпаргалке это win1252, в сравнениях phpmyadmin нет такой кодировки

Comment: В стандартном виндовом блокноте? DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 это в самом файле написано?

Comment: это и есть в стандартном виндовом блокноте. да, в самом файле

Comment: @ЖалгасАжибаев, посмотрите на картинку которую вы вставили в вопрос, и на картинку в ответе: судя по всему у вас ситуация - UTF-8 -> Win-1252

Comment: @Grundy  есть функция декодирования 'iconv' но работает 50 на 50. Половину не перевело(((

Comment: @ЖалгасАжибаев Да хватит мозг парить...... я вам же сказал что делать...неужели танцы с бубном с переводом кодировки проще чем открыть файл в блокноте и сменить его кодировку?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мужик, я воспользовался и твоей картинкой и другой, спасибо, она мне ничего не дала. Просто неправильно вопрос задал, потом задал другой, правильный, ты же сам на него отвечал.http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495677/%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-php/495710#495710

Comment: @ЖалгасАжибаев Хочешь сказать ты открывал файл в блокноте как я рекомендовал и в меню выбирал кодировку `UTF-8 БЕЗ BOM` после чего залил в БД и все равно крякозябры? Или ничего не дала в том плане, что так и не понял что от тебя хотят? Ибо я думаю что второе.. а второй твой путь - путь к костылям

Comment: @АлексейШиманский файл изначально шел UTF-8 БЕЗ BOM. Т.е. когда ты сказал посмотри картинку, я посмотрел, попробовал и кодировка уже была  UTF-8 БЕЗ BOM

Comment: С кодировками, php и БД не всегда все просто. Сюда еще прибавляются проблемы с разными версиями. Даже если для базы указана определенная кодировка, сами данные могут быть совсем другой. При работе клиента (скрипта) с БД можно указать в какой кодировке получать (принимать) данные. Например, в БД хранится UTF-8,  клиент просит выдать в cp1251, никаких проблем нет, все работает. А если попросить в cp1252, то вместо кириллицы будут "кракозябры", потому что её нет в этой кодировке. Очень понятная статья http://phpfaq.ru/mysql/charset