# есть ли функция декодирования (конвертации кодировки) строки в php?

Tags: php, кодировка, кириллица, функции

как я это вижу:

```
$done = волшебная_функция_декодирования($before,"CP1252");
```

Comment: Возможно `iconv` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да! но работает 50 на 50. Половину не перевело(((;
интересно получается
`echo iconv("UTF-8", "CP1252", 'ÐœÐ¸Ð½Ð¶Ð°ÑÐ°Ñ€Ð¾Ð²Ð°'); //пусто, ничего не выводится)`
`echo iconv("UTF-8", "CP1252", 'ÐšÑƒÐ°Ð½Ñ‹ÑˆÐµÐ²Ð½Ð°');  //Куанышевна`
`echo iconv("UTF-8", "CP1252", 'HR-Ð¼ÐµÐ½ÐµÐ´Ð¶ÐµÑ€');   //HR-менеджер`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть mb_convert_encoding().
Есть [документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)
И есть хороший [практический пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469212/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%83/469321#469321)

Comment: дай я тебя расцелую!

Comment: Кстати: практический пример тоже мой)